# My WiFI keeps disconnecting

Tags: wireless, asus

My WiFI keeps disconnecting on my Asus X75V, the installation is cool, and in recent days, I keep disconnecting from the Internet.

Can you give me the steps to give you more information so that you can help me solve this problem?

Thank you!

**rfkill list**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux maxence 4.13.0-19-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 11:58:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e054]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

When I type:

> sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

I get this error:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée

(gedit:26123): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu , please [edit here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/989143/edit) by adding the output of `rfkill list` , `uname -a` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` add the following line `blacklist asus-nb-wmi` save and reboot.

Comment: I tried to type `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` but I get an error. I've updated my first post.

Comment: Use `nano` instead of `gedit` ,  `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: Indeed! I try this!